# how use two modeles in one method?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

the ModelState is Invalid.I Think I pass Model Wrongly.Any Idea?

controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendComment([Bind("CommentID,Comment,Date,AdminId")]AdminReport adminReport,int ReportID)
    {
        var x = _userReport.UserReports.Find(ReportID);
        x.IsViewed = true;
        adminReport.UserId = x.UserId;
        adminReport.AdminId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
        if (ModelState.IsValid){
            _adminReport.Add(adminReport);
            await _adminReport.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View(); }

        return RedirectToAction("SendDoneAdmin");
    }
```

its how I pass a Model:

```
 <div class="card-footer">
    <form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="ُSendComment" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="@report.ReportID" name="ReportID" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SendComment</button>
    </form>
```

Model:
        [Key]
        public int CommentID { get; set; }

```
    [Required]
    public string Comment { get; set; }


    public string AdminId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotation no clear but must know for pass data via **Form** tag
must all input inside **Form** tag

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendComment()
{
    // write your code....
    return View(new AdminReport()); // must return new object
}
```

**POST**

> Normal write again your action **SendComment** no any change

**HTML**

for pass *AdminReport* model must write flied inside form tag

```
<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Viewed" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="@report.ReportID" name="ReportID" />
    /* for example */
    <input type="hidden"  asp-for="model.Comment" /> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SendComment</button>
</form>
```

> No Problem if you have another view but must return View(new AdminReport());

If you want remove validation for comment prop use below code.

```
 // remove all key
    foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys).ToList())
                ModelState.Remove(key);
  // or for one
  ModelState.Remove("comment ");
```

Comment: actually I have another view for my "SendComment"method.but it doesn't show because ModelState is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You put this `[Requiried]` attribute on the `Comment`:

```
    [Required]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
```

You will have to include that input in your form in order for the validation to pass.
You can add that field like this:

```
 <div class="card-footer">
    <form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Viewed" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="@report.ReportID" name="ReportID" />
        <input type="text" name="Comment" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SendComment</button>
    </form>
```